# Comparing two datareaders from different db in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, ado.net

I have two different databases with the same properties in some columns.
The objective of my repository is get those properties and compare it.

So i did it this way:

```
public sealed class Product
{
    public string BarCode{ get; set; }
    public string CreationDate{ get; set; }
    public string Modifier{ get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsDB1()
{
    //  ADO.NET stuff using DataReader returning a Product List from DB1
}

public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsDB2()
{
    //  ADO.NET stuff using DataReader returning a Product List from DB2
}

public IEnumerable<Product> Compare()
{
   var db2 = GetProductsDB2()
   var db1 = GetProductsDB1()
   //Comparing both lists here and returning the result list to display in GridView
}
```

Im not sure if it is the best approach to do that. I would like to have any suggestion to do that using the right concepts. Because this comparision is painful and i have more than 30 objects to compare doing the same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting the same products to exist in both lists? If so, is there an identifier unique to each product?

If there is a unique identifier available, you are looking to do a join between your two lists (a full outer join in this case, containing all records from each list).

Edit:
Assuming we are using a property "CodeBar" of product, you can use code such as the following to compare things:

```
  var tJoined = db1.Join(db2, 
    list1Product => list1Product.CodeBar,
    list2Product => list2Product.CodeBar,
    (list1Product, list2Product) => new { Product1 = list1Product, Product2 = list2Product }
  );

  foreach(var tProductComparision in tJoined) {
    if(tProductComparison.Product1.PropertyOfInterest != tProductComparison.Product2.PropertyOfInterest) {
      //do something here
    }
  }
```

Comment: theres no unique identifier. And yes, the products exist in the same list.

Comment: What comparison are you hoping to do then?

Comment: In the process workflow, the product is added in the same time in these two third part db, but sometimes the data is corrupted and the values are not the same. So i need to check it and display.

Comment: Right, but how do you plan on making sure you are comparing the correct product in each list?

Comment: For example, in this case, i have the CodeBar, it will be the Unique Identifier.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include some psuedo code that should point you in the correct direction, it is possible for elements that don't line up for either Product1 or Product2 to be null (in the case where a product doesn't exist in one list or the other)